# Performing nested foreach loops in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I've never done this in knockout before, so surely I've just got something wrong.

I have a jsfiddle here that shows the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/pdavis68/xebq7/

And here is the relevant HTML:

```
    <!-- ko foreach: Parameters -->
        <select data-bind="attr: { id: Name }">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.ValidValues -->
            <option data-bind="value: Value, text: Label"></option>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </select>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

and the relevant Javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Parameters = ko.observableArray();
}
var currentItem;

$(document).ready() {
    currentItem = new ViewModel();       
    ko.applyBindings(currentItem);

    currentItem.Parameters.push(
        [{"Name":"WarehouseCode", "ValidValues":
          [{"Label":"Warehouse 1-- (01)","Value":"01"},
           {"Label":"Warehouse 2 -- (02)","Value":"02"}]}]);
}
```

My goal, of course, is to have the ValidValues used to populate the `<option>` tags in my `<select>` and as you can see from the jsFiddle, that's not happening.

How do I correct my HTML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. Your `document.ready(...)` syntax is wrong. You want that block to look something like:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () { ... }); // <-- note the "function"
   ```
2. You're pushing an array into your observable array of items. You really want to *update* the observable array with the new values:

   ```
   currentItem.Parameters([{
       "Name": "WarehouseCode",
       "ValidValues": [{
           "Label": "Warehouse 1-- (01)",
           "Value": "01"
       }, {
           "Label": "Warehouse 2 -- (02)",
           "Value": "02"
       }]
   }]);
   ```
3. You were including neither KnockoutJS nor jQuery in the fiddle.

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xebq7/1/